# Changing border of Control

Tags: c#, .net

Im having a problem with setting custom border of Control. This border can be done with DrawRectangle, DrawBorder or anything else as long as I get this behaviour

[image]

Obviously, the darkest border is where previouse border was. Other borders are around it trying to mimic fade out(or whatever). Now, the most challenging thing is I cannot override OnPaint or extend any other Control. This HAS to work on all Controls!
This is part of my extender provider whith which I set these borders when control has focus(like Google Chrome).

So far I have come up with this...
When adding controls in extender provider dictionary I hook up on Enter and Leave events of control. In there I get the parent of the control that is firing the event and on that form I draw these 3 rectangles. That way I sorted painting on non client area. The thing that remains is painting the actual border of control. I have tried and tried but to no avail.

I also hooked up on paint event of that control but ControlPaint.DrawBorder() is not working.

Okay, so this is method that is getting called on Enter and leave.

```
private void BojajGlow(Graphics gfx, Graphics gfxCtrl, Control parent, Control kontrola, bool novi)
    {
        Rectangle[] rect = new Rectangle[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int x = kontrola.Location.X - (i + 1);
            int y = kontrola.Location.Y - (i + 1);
            int w = kontrola.Size.Width + 2 * (i + 1) - 1;
            int h = kontrola.Size.Height + 2 * (i + 1) - 1;
            rect[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
        }

        if (novi)
        {
            Color boja = DohvatiOpcije(kontrola).Boja;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    boja = Posvjetli(95, ControlPaint.Light(boja));
                Pen olovka = new Pen(boja);
                olovka.EndCap = olovka.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                olovka.Width = 1;

                GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();
                gfxPath.AddRectangle(rect[i]);

                gfx.DrawPath(olovka, gfxPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Pen olovka = new Pen(parent.BackColor);
                olovka.EndCap = olovka.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                olovka.Width = 1;

                GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();
                gfxPath.AddRectangle(rect[i]);

                gfx.DrawPath(olovka, gfxPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

From Enter event it is going to be called like this

```
if (((Control)sender).Parent != null)
            BojajGlow(Graphics.FromHwnd(((Control)sender).Parent.Handle), Graphics.FromHwnd(((Control)sender).Handle), ((Control)sender).Parent, (Control)sender, true);
```

Does anyone have any valuable input on this?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I am using WinForms. I don't know WPF but I've seen some examples in it where this is trivial to achieve :)

Comment: The border is drawn using the user selected theme settings with the default handler for the WM_NCPAINT message.  A difficult message to deal with.  Simplest way is to just use borderless controls and let the parent draw a border.

Answer (score 0):

In winforms you are probably going to need to create your own custom control inheriting from the TextBox control. In your control you can implement the OnPaint based on the controls state such as whether or not it has focus.

As for drawing outside of the control, dont. It will only frustrate you. Instead draw three boarders using the forms background color WITHIN your control and change them to the hightlighted color when you need them to glow.

Hope this helps.